# I'd like to add a header to the 500 Internal Server Error page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2, http-headers

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and my application works mostly using JSON queries.

If something goes wrong on the server-side, I get the standard "500 Internal Server Error" page. That's actually fine. But I'd like to add one more field in the response headers : the Exception's Message.

My idea was to add this override in the controller :

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Exception", filterContext.Exception.Message);
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the new field in the response headers.

However, if do this on my controller's methods, it works:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Exception", ex.Message);
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    return Content(ex.Message);
}
```

It works, but it's not very neat. Is there a way I can do this easily? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling custom errors in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

This will render the standard error view `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` and your custom header will be appended to the response.

Also you could use `filterContext.HttpContext.Response` instead of `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response`. It points to the same object, it's just that it makes a little more sense.

Comment: That's rather annoying, but it seems I always get the IIS error page, whatever I do in the web.config or in the code. Even the standard ASP.NET MVC sample is not giving me the custom error page (I do use CustomErrors On there too...)

Comment: @TigrouMeow, is your controller decorated with the `[HandleError]` attribute?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: In the controller's methods. I just edited my question, I found a way that works, but that isn't ideal.

Comment: Does the `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` file exist?

Comment: Yes, I have the original one.

Comment: Are you running this on IIS or Cassini?

Comment: Try using it. It's the Visual Studio's built-in server. In the properties of the project you could specify this.

Comment: Okay, so I tried with both of them already. I really don't understand what it doesn't work both on my project and the sample project of MVC. It's really weird. Anyway, maybe I'll go with the TRY-CATCH solution, at least IIS (or Cassini) doesn't replace my error page this way (even I change the StatusCode to InternalServerError).